# We should use gerund or verb after comma?

Tags: grammar

Parents are all the same, love their children.

Parents are all the same, loving their children.

Which sentence above is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

The second is the correct example, but I don't believe "loving" is the gerund in this case, just the present participle of the verb.

You wouldn't say "Parents are love their children", it makes no grammatical sense. It should be "parents love their children". You might say "parents are loving their children", although it isn't particularly idiomatic. Still, it shows how a verb can be used in the present participle in a similar context to your example.

A gerund is a verb used as a noun. "Loving their children" is verb-determiner-noun. If "loving" was a noun, where's the verb? An example of "loving" as a gerund would be "Parents give their children some loving".